# Attempting to run samba with a LaunchAgent - process won't start with system

Tags: smb

I've installed Samba3 from MacPorts. (following [this guide](http://forums.boxee.tv/showthread.php?t=38629)) To run it I execute `sudo /opt/local/sbin/smbd -D && sudo /opt/local/sbin/nmbd -D` in a Terminal window and everything works fine.

I've attempted to create a LaunchAgent to run samba with the system, rather than having to invoke it manually. My plist file is called `com.samba3.plist` and consists of the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.samba3</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/opt/local/sbin/smbd</string>
<string>-D</string>
<string>&amp;&amp;</string>
<string>/opt/local/sbin/nmbd</string>
<string>-D</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, on system startup samba is not being run.

Answer (score 1):

I see several things that need fixing:

1. This should be installed as a LaunchDaemon, not a LaunchAgent.  The difference is that an agent runs inside a user login session, as the user; a daemon runs independent of who is or isn't logged in, and generally runs as root (which you need here).
2. The ProgramArgument list isn't parsed by a shell, so `&&` doesn't do what you want -- it's just passed as an argument to smbd.  You really should make two launchd items, one for smbd and one for nmbd.
3. The `-D` flag to each program tells it to daemonize, i.e. detach and run in the background; launchd expects the things it launches to stay connected so it can monitor them (and in fact will think a program has quit if it daemonizes).  Remove the `-D` flags, and use `-F` instead.

Also, if you have Snow Leopard (installed or available) take a look at the launchd items that start the system's version of smbd and nmbd; they're /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/smbd.plist and .../nmbd.plist.  They contain some additional tricks which you may find useful.  Most notably, nmbd is set to auto-relaunch if the network is up, and smbd is only launched on demand when a connection is received.

Comment: Very nice answer.  Dense and informative.  +1